# Importing PropTypes to set color for Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

So, I am trying to add controls to my Storybook components. I am having trouble figuring out how to change the css styling. I've set up proptypes to help me handle the background color of the component, but I don't know how to bring that into my stories. Right now, my background color is nothing. I would like it to be a specific color to start. I am using React. I added my code below, any help is appreciated!

Style.js:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { colors } from '../utilities';

export const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: ${colors.text500};
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: ${props => props.color};
`;

StyledButton.PropTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default StyledButton;
```

Button.stories.js

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { colors } from '../utilities';

export default {
  title: "Button",
  component: Button
};

export const Primary = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

Primary.args = {
  label: 'Download',
  color: '${colors.primary500}',
};
```

Comment: Use [`.defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)

Comment: @JosephD. where?

Comment: @JosephD. I've tried changing it like this and several other ways but it is not working:export const Primary = (args, props) => <Button {...args, props} />;

Primary.args.defaultProps = {
  label: 'Download',
  background: '${colors.primary500}',
};

Comment: Try `Primary.defaultProps`.

Comment: @JosephD. I did, unfortunately that doesn't work either.